# How to Enable QuickPath (Swipe) keyboard on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, ipados

iOS 13 delivered a a new “swipe to type” keyboard called *QuickPath*.  [New features available with iOS 13](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13/features/).  This is similar to the [Word Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8.1#Keyboard) on Windows Phones and the [Swipe Keyboard](https://appstipsandtricks.com/download-swype-keyboard/) for Android.

[image: QuickPath Animated GIF]

It’s enabled by default on the iPhone, but not on the iPad. How can I enable this useful feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This requires the floating keyboard.**

To use the [floating keyboard](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210758), simply use the “pinch” gesture on the keyboard as if you were “pinching to zoom out.” The floating keyboard will appear.  You can then use the QuickPath (swipe) keyboard functionality.

If you need to move the keyboard, simply drag it by holding the grey bar at the bottom and dragging it to your desired location.

To restore the keyboard back to full size, either drag it to the bottom of the screen or use the "pinch out" gesture.