# How to make iPad software split keyboard identical to the iPhone default one?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ipad

The iPad software split keyboard is slightly different than the iPhone, which makes it infuriatingly difficult to type when you barely use the iPad.

Is there a way to make the iPad split keyboard basically the same as the default iPhone keyboard?

Comment: What specifically do you mean with "different" and "same"?

Comment: Also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/383180/119271

Answer (score 1):

### Floating keyboard

To use the floating keyboard feature, you have to :

1. Click on a text box to make your soft keyboard appear.
2. Long-click on the button at the bottom right of your keyboard and select "Floating".

[image: Click on the button at the bottom right and click on "Floating"]

You should be able to see a movable keyboard that is about the same size as the keyboard on iPhone (see the picture below).

[image]

<sub>*(Click on images to open full size)*</sub>